# Python module changes aren't being imported

Tags: python, import, module

I've got a python sub-project referencing a module in a higher directory:

```
/
    misc/
        subproject/
            main2.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        main1.py
```

To run main2 I `cd` to the `subproject/` directory and run

```
PYTHONPATH=../.. main2.py
```

In main2 I'm trying to use new functions that I've written into main1, but I'm getting an

```
AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'function name').
```

Running `dir(main1)` after the import shows me that none of the functions I added are present in the module; I commented out the entire file and tried importing it, but `dir(main1)` showed all the old top-level declarations, with none of them removed. This made me think it's a caching problem, even though I've cleared any `*.pyc` files I can find.

Comment: What does `print main1.__file__` show is the filename of the imported module?

Comment: You genius, I had installed the main1 project before so main2 was importing from that instead. Is there some way of uninstalling or overwriting the path order?

Comment: You can manipulate `sys.path` directly, but that should be a last resort, really.

Comment: Yeah... Actually, I'll probably just reinstall the main1 project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could always try changing the name of your modules so they are unique and relevant.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't actually use these kinds of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed the main1 project, so even though I had set my PYTHONPATH to include the current version of the main1 project, the installed version was what was getting imported, and so shadowing the updates I was making to the code.

Thanks to Martijn Pieters for pointing me to using `print main1.__file__` to see what actual file the main1 module was being imported from.